# How to do Conditional check Date should not be blank in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a date model  ( project.CreateDate ) in my c# project, how do i can conditionally check that Date is not null, like

```
//i know this can not be applied, because it is type of Date and string
if (project.CreateDate != "" ){  

    //other process

}
```

so how do i can check?

Comment: which typeof is `.CreateDate`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `.CreateDate` is of type `System.Nullable<DateTime>` you could easily do the following check:

```
if (project.CreateDate.HasValue)
```

or

```
if (project.CreateDate != null)
```

and maybe enhance this with

```
if (project.CreateDate.HasValue && DateTime.MinValue < project.CreateDate.Value)
```

Otherwise you might go the ugly path eg

```
if (project.CreateDate != DateTime.MinValue)
```

or

```
if (DateTime.MinValue < project.CreateDate)
```

If `.CreateDate` is of type `System.String` you go for

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(project.CreateDate))
```

or with .NET 4.0 and `System.String`

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(project.CreateDate))
```

I strongly encourage you to use `System.Nullable<DateTime>` (aka `System.DateTime?`) to go for the first solution. The value `System.DateTime.MinValue` might always be a "non-real"-value, but you will lose the possibility of using `System.DateTime.MinValue` in your application (compare to not be able to use `0` in your application) as a real-value

Comment: Thx Andreas, you gave me different thought to check in different way.

Answer (score 3):

A `DateTime` that is not set otherwise to a given date will have a default value of `DateTime.MinValue`. You can compare against that:

```
if (project.CreateDate != DateTime.MinValue)
{
     // can use date
}
```

If it is actually a nullable date (`Nullable<DateTime>` or just `DateTime?`), the default value will simply be the functional equivalent of null.

```
if (project.CreateDate != null) // for nullable dates
```

Comment: yes, this is perfect to my code  if (project.CreateDate != null) // for nullable dates

Answer (score 2):

Date is a value type so if the variable is not declared as nullable, if it is you can use `project.CreateDate.HasValue`, othwerise you can test it against the default value:

```
if (project.CreateDate != default(DateTime))
{

}
```

Comment: what will be in default(DateTime)?

Comment: @manny `default(System.DateTime)` is equal to `System.DateTime.MinValue`

Comment: a value type always has a default value like int will be 0. For DateTime it is the mininimum value which is 0001/01/01 12:00:00 AM.